# Notify when onPause() called in any activity of an application

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I think this question may simple  but I didn't find any solution for this,

I there any way in Android that if any one of an activity calls `onPause()` I need to show Toast message or any notification kind of thing need to show. Generally I want to get notified when activity calls `onPause()` but I need it in one place since I may have some 15 activity I don't want to add it in all the activity.

ex:If I have  activity when any one of the activity calls `onPause` I need to get notified but that notification code should be in one place and we should not add any line of code `onPause()` Is it possible to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly create a BaseActivity which extends AppCompatActivity then extends BaseActivity in your all activity.Put your Toast/Notification in BaseActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a baseActivity, which has for example :

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Toast.makeText(this, "notified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Then you can extends this in your activities and handle the on pause call in BaseActivity

Answer (score 0):

If your `minSdkVersion` >= 14, you can use `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`: [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)

You have to define a custom `Application` class and you can register for this callbacks afterwards:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

  private class LifecycleCallbacks implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Activity activity, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(final Activity activity) {
        //nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(final Activity activity) {
        // TODO Do your stuff, e.g. show toast.
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(final Activity activity) {
        //nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(final Activity activity, final Bundle outState) {
        //nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(final Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(final Activity activity) {

    }
  }

  private final LifecycleCallbacks callbacks;

  public void onCreate() { 
    super.onCreate();
    callbacks = new LifecycleCallbacks();
    application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(callbacks);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a BaseActivity which contain all the methods you want to use in all other activities.

Then extend every activity with BaseActivity to call onPause() method.